# How to access object property in angular using string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript

I have this object in my component ts file that looks like this:

```
 someData = {
      someValue: null,
      unit: "centimeters"
    },
```

In my template (html file) I have to verify the value of **"someValue**" property. If its value is null then display the unit, else display the value of someValue and unit together. I have the below code but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

```
<div>{{ someData?.someValue === null ? someData?.someValue.unit : someData?.someValue someData?.unit }}</div >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngif` to check the condition and show the data:

```
<div *ngIf="someData?.someValue === null">{{someData.unit}}</div>
<div *ngIf="someData?.someValue!= null">{{someData.someValue}} {{someData.unit}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two values at the end aren't going to render right, because it's executable javascript, not HTML when inside the double brackets.

I would suggest splitting this into two lines of HTML.

```html
<div *ngIf="someData?.someValue; else unit_only">{{someData.someValue}} {{someData.unit}}</div>
<ng-template #unit_only>{{someData?.unit}}</ng-template>
```

Or you could try sticking with your original approach...

```html
<div>{{ someData?.someValue === null ? someData?.unit : someData?.someValue + ' ' + someData?.unit }}</div>
```